# How to add FULLSCREEN control properly?

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers

I am trying to add a full screen control (I had a switcher too). when i create this control inside map creation  `new ol.MAP...`(following documentation) i dont get errors but they(layersSwitcher and Fullscreen control) dont appear.

```
map = new ol.Map({
        controls:[new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
            tipLabel: 'Leyenda',
    
        }),
        new ol.control.defaults().extend([new ol.control.FullScreen()])],
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Group({
                'title': 'Mapas de base',
                layers: [grisOSM, mapaOSM]
            }),
```

I also tried creating the map, then create and add controls like this:

```
 map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Group({
                'title': 'Mapas de base',
                layers: [grisOSM, mapaOSM]
            }),

    const layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
        tipLabel: 'Leyenda',

    });
    map.addControl(layerSwitcher);
    const fullScreen = new ol.control.defaults().extend([new ol.control.FullScreen()]);

    map.addControl(fullScreen);
```

I get `Uncaught TypeError: t.element.setMap is not a function` error and can't see none of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either

```
 map = new ol.Map({
        controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([new ol.control.FullScreen()]),
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Group({
                'title': 'Mapas de base',
                layers: [grisOSM, mapaOSM]
            }),
         ],
     });
```

or

```
 map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Group({
                'title': 'Mapas de base',
                layers: [grisOSM, mapaOSM]
            })
        ],
    });

    map.addControl(new ol.control.FullScreen());
```

`ol.control.defaults` is not a constructor so does not need `new`